# "circular" interval tree algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, interval-tree

I'm wondering if anyone has implemented/knows of an (preferably javascript) interval-tree algorithm that will handle circular intervals. By circular, I mean intervals with a start > end. Note this also necessitates a cap to how large the intervals can be.

Is this just a subcase of the common interval tree problem?

In response to the questions posed in the comments: 
Here's an image (thanks G. Bach and wikipedia) of what I mean by a circular subrange: [image]

And (unrelated to the above image) here's an example json representation of the ranges:
[{id: 'range1', start: 3, end: 34}, {id: 'range2circular', start: 30, end:6}]

Hope

Thanks!

Comment: please supply some example.

Comment: You could simply reverse each of those intervals with negative length so if an interval is `(start, end)` and `start > end` then store `(end, start, R)` where R notes that this interval is reversed. The you can use a normal interval tree and then know from the `R` that a given result has its start and end reversed.

Comment: From what domain are your values? How do they wrap around?

Comment: @DanD.: Not exactly, because you'd have to invert your search as well.

Comment: I don't see any logical connection between the qualifier "circular" and bounds reversal "start >end". I don't think that you are telling us the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds related to the idea behind [circular arc graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular-arc_graph) (but not the graphs themselves, since you start out with the intervals and don't care about a circular arc graph representation of them).

Assuming that's what it is, that means the domain can be represented by a period akin to the degrees of a circle. Then you have a minimum possible value `min` and a maximum possible value `max = min + 1*period`, and the first thing you do is find the smallest `s` such that `start = min + s + k*period` for integer `k` (basically, this is a modulo operation), and similarly you find the smallest `e` such that `end = min + e + j*period`.

Now you can represent your interval as `(s,e)` still with `s > e`. Split it up into two intervals `(s, max)` and `(min, e)`, throw those into your interval tree, and give both of them a reference to your original interval `(start, end)`. If you start with `n` intervals that possibly overlap a period, you end up with `2n` intervals in the tree, and the asymptotic bounds hold.